# How to accept the payment with regtest?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I sent some BTC via the regtest network from one wallet to another, and I don't see it using `getbalance`, but I do see it if I use the command `getbalances` as `untrusted_pending`:

```
{
  "mine": {
    "trusted": 0.00000000,
    "untrusted_pending": 2.00000000,
    "immature": 0.00000000
  }
}
```

What does it mean? And how can I accept it? Will it also happen in the mainnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`untrusted_pending` means `untrusted pending balance (outputs created by others that are in the mempool)` according to the bitcoin core source.

If you create a new block and it contains above payment transaction, it will show in `trusted`.

Comment: You're right! I added a block and it worked. I noticed there are two options to generate blocks: `generatetoaddress` and `generateblocks`, what's the difference?

Comment: The `generatetoaddress` automatically picks up transactions from the set of transactions in the mempool and creates a block. 
`generateblock` RPC, on the other hand, is an RPC added in 0.21.0. It takes an argument to specify the set of transactions (via txid or rawtx) to be included in the generated block. This is useful to include another Tx in the block that conflicts with the Tx in the mempool, or to create a block where a particular Tx is not mined.

Comment: Thank you! You made it clear